# Apple Remote Desktop (ARD) 3.7 - how to drag n drop copy files from local to remote

Tags: remote-desktop

I've been able to use Apple Remote Desktop to copy files and folders from my local machine to remotes for many years. I've updated to ARD 3.7 and I can longer copy files. Is this no longer supported or is there some setting I need to change? I've looked and tried many things with no luck. How can I drag n drop files from my local Mac to the Remotes?

Comment: Have the client Macs been updated with the proper ARD Client updates?  Sending "softwareupdate -i -a" will run available software updates on the clients. What version of the OS are the clients running?

Comment: clients are running 3.7 ARD client and same OS 10.8.5

Comment: In the past I lost the ability to do this when the client had file sharing turned off. Turning it back on re-enabled the function. I seem to recall one of the recent updates on 10.8 disabled some of the services on a couple of my machines. Worth checking that it's still enabled.

Comment: It's definitely still supported, it's in the release notes of Apple Remote Desktop 3.7 (Build 3055) that it's still supported.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the file copy still works on the newer versions including ARD 3.7.1 so it's something you'll need to use logs to troubleshoot.

You may have to use the copy tool to try copying the file and look over the logs to determine what has changed between your remote computers and the controlling remote desktop computer.

That interface has better error messages and reporting and has helped me figure out what firewall settings were preventing me from using ARD in the past. Feel free to post your log if you can't make sense of the details it lists.

Comment: If someone wants to downvote an answer, please add a comment to explain why

Answer (score 0):

At the client, try:

1. disable remote management
2. enable screen sharing
3. enable remote management

– and a restart of the Mac.

Also, you could try the kickstart routine.

Comment: This did not resolve the problem. Are you running ARD 3.7 and able to copy using drag n drop from local to remote?